# WooCommerce sort by SKU

Tags: wp-query

So, I've tried https://gist.github.com/bekarice/1883b7e678ec89cc8f4d on my website. It works good, as long as all the products have SKU. If a product doesn't have SKU, it's not displayed at all.

This being said, is there any other way to sort by SKU but not require product to actually have SKU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use with woocommerce plugin and theme already css and code.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'       => '_sku',
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
            'order'          => 'DESC',
          );
query_posts( $args );
if( have_posts() ) :
  while (have_posts()): the_post();
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```